# Different results with the same version of CMake

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, linker, linker-errors

I have a desktop PC and a notebook, and I'm using both of them to build a same C++ project. Everything on both are exact same version, such as my source codes / g++ / cmake / kdevelop / rpclib..., but the desktop PC was been installed one year ago (Kubuntu-20.04.1), while the notebook has a refresh installation (Kubuntu-20.04.4).

On my notebook, the cmake (3.16.3) enforces me to specify a lib with a form like `target_link_libraries( my_target rpclib::rpc )`.

On my desktop, the cmake (same version) enforces me do it with a form like `target_link_libraries( my_target ${RPCLIB_LIBS} )`, though the both has the exact same verson.

I know a little about the traditional way how cmake find a library, i.e the `Findrpclib.cmake` file in `/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules` will get be executed and set a few of variables such as ${RPCLIB_LIBS}. In my desktop, this file **DOES** exists in above folder, and the statement `find_package( rpclib REQUIRED )` executes successfully.

But in the notebook, there is **NO** such a file in the same folder.
The strange thing is that `find_package( rpclib REQUIRED )` passed quietly, and `${RPCLIB_LIBS}` has nothing.

I don't know what magic it done, let me can and must specify the lib with `rpclib:rpc` on my notebook. Even though I copy a Findrpclib.cmake file into the corresponding folder, it still report that `${RPCLIB_LIBS}` is empty!

It's annoying to modify the codes when I switch environment between the two PCs.

Is there a way, I can successfully build my codes on the both environments without modify my cmake codes repeatedly?

The following things are installed by using `apt install` from the same repository on the both PC, and has been updated to the same version:

1. cmake (3.16.3)
2. gcc/g++ (9.4.0)

The **rpclib (2.3.0)** was built from the source and installed with `make install`.

Comment: No magic! it's called cache. Make 100% sure all CMake cache is cleared and you should get a more proper result.

Comment: @Top-Master Thanks for you hint! How to clear the cache?

Comment: @Top-Master I tried many times to delete the building tree before re-building. I build this project out of the source tree, so it is very simple and safe.

Comment: Unfortunately it's hard to exclude CMake cache from source-tree (hence I don't remember how I did that), and if all you do is delete build-result, then you need to search-for and delete CMake cache from source-tree.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible in your case, but to ensure CMake dose not make the source-tree dirty, I do `cmake -H. -B .build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G "Unix Makefiles"` (change generator to your need).

Comment: If the find module is missing then something in the setup of the lib went differently on both machines. You could certainly add a workaround that makes the project work on both system without modification, but I recommend figuring out the difference between the setup on both machines. Checking the diff of the `CMakeCache.txt` files on both machines could provide some info...

Comment: "In my desktop, this file DOES exists in above folder ..." - There is NO file `/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/Findrpclib.cmake` in the [cmake-data package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/cmake-data/filelist). And no other package is allowed to install files under `/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules`. You also won't find description of that module in [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/manual/cmake-modules.7.html). Looks like this file is created by you. You could check timestamp of that file and compare it with timestamps of other files in `/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules`.

Comment: Probably, you have taken that [Findrpclib.cmake](https://github.com/rpclib/rpclib/blob/master/cmake/Findrpclib.cmake) file and copied it into `/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/` (despite the description of the file tells "Findrpclib.cmake can be distributed with the **source of your software**"). Exactly that script sets `RPCLIB_LIBS` variable. Futher versions of rpclib seems to distribute [rpclibConfig.cmake](https://github.com/rpclib/rpclib/blob/master/cmake/rpclibConfig.cmake.in) script, which defines `rpclib::rpc` IMPORTED target instead.